# How to get data from hidden 'id' column in QtableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Using a qTableWidget to view my sqlite database entries.
The first column of the database is hidden since it's the ID that gets auto assigned to an entry.

Now I want the user to select the row he wants to delete and then be able to press the delete button.
I'm using the following to do that:

```
class StartScherm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartScherm, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.database_laden()
        # -- Button presses with .connect -- #
        
        self.tableSnelleKijk.doubleClicked.connect(self.weergave_scherm)
        self.tableSnelleKijk.setSelectionBehavior(
            QtWidgets.QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.tableSnelleKijk.setColumnHidden(0, True)
```

Now I'm trying to make a function that once the users clicks on the delete button in the GUI, the function reads the ID so I can delete it from the sqlite database. I use this:

```
def delete(self):
        index = self.tableSnelleKijk.selectedItems()
        print(index[0].text())
```

unfortunately, this gives me the first visable column data as text instead of the hidden columnwith the ID.

How do I access the hidden data?

EDIT: changed column to row
The database is hidden on the tableview only, in sqlite it's simply there to have a rowID I can use to access a current row to delete/edit.

Database  code:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Medailles (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
            orde text,
            periode text,
            locatie text,
            beschrijving text
            )""")
```

The column is hidden in the QtableView with .setColumnHidden.
The database gets populated when the users decides to enter a new entry, this is the function that takes care of this:

```
def add(self):
        orde = self.orde_comboBox.currentText()
        periode = self.periode_input.text()
        locatie = self.locatie_input.text()
        beschrijving = self.beschrijving_input.toPlainText()

        medaille = Medaille(orde, periode, locatie, beschrijving)
        with conn:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO Medailles (orde, periode, locatie, beschrijving) VALUES (:orde, :periode, :locatie, :beschrijving)", {
                'orde': medaille.orde, 'periode': medaille.periode, 'locatie': medaille.locatie, 'beschrijving': medaille.beschrijving})
        self.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in an invisible column, the items in that column cannot be selected. You can access those indexes (and their data) by using the [`sibling(row, column)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#sibling) function (or [`siblingAtColumn(column)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#siblingAtColumn) for Qt>=5.11):

```
    def delete(self):
        rows = set()
        for index in self.tableSnelleKijk.selectedItems():
            id = index.sibling(index.row(), 0).text()
            rows.add(id)
        print('IDs to delete: {}'.format(sorted(rows)))
```

Do note that if you need to write data to the database or edit its layout you should consider using a basic QTableView with a [QtSql.QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) instead, otherwise you might face some inconsistencies, bugs or even data corruption if you're not really careful with your implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I'm better off using that QSqlTableModel like you mentioned, since it's a program to add, edit, delete items from a collection. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a hidden column in a QTableWidget (PyQt5):

```
row = self.tblWidget.currentRow()
col = position of hidden column - usually 0
ID  = self.tblWidget.item(row,col).text()
```